# How to check if comment ( text) belongs to current user by uid

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I am trying to create a function where users can delete their own comment/report others.

I've done this with the post so I assumed I would use the same method..which is grabbing the owner of the comments UID and check if that is the current user or not. If it is the current user then I will set up the alert controller to display "delete" else it'll be "report"

Here is a sample code of the post function that works correctly

```swift
  func handleOptionsTapped(for cell: FollowingCell) {

 guard let post = cell.post else { return }

        // If post belongs to current user display delete action sheet.. else report

if post.ownerUid == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Post", style: .destructive, handler: { (_) in
                post.deletePost()
```

Also the post value in `FollowingCell`

```swift
 var post: Post? {
        didSet {
            guard let ownerUid = post?.ownerUid else { return }
            guard let imageUrl = post?.imageUrl else { return }


            Database.fetchUserWithUID(with: ownerUid) { (user) in
                self.profileImage.loadImage(with: user.profileImageUrl)
                self.username.setTitle(user.username, for: .normal)
                self.configurePostCaption(user: user)
            }
            postImage.loadImage(with: imageUrl)
            configureLikeButton()



            }
}
```

Here is the code I have for comments

```swift
   @objc func handleCommentTapped(for cell: CommentCell) {


         guard let comment = cell.comment else { return }

        // If comment belongs to the current user

        if comment.uid == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            print("this is my comment")

        } else {
            print("this is another users comment")
        }

    }
```

Also here is the code I have for the `CommentCell`

```swift
 var comment: Comment? {

            didSet {
                guard let comment = self.comment else { return }
                guard let uid = comment.uid else { return }
                guard let user = self.comment?.user else { return }
                guard let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl else { return }

                Database.fetchUserWithUID(with: uid) { (user) in

                    self.profileImageView.loadImage(with: profileImageUrl)

                    self.configureCommentLabel()

                }
            }
    }
```

When I run the program I get a crash

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, address=0x1a2494098a1)

on the line `guard let comment = cell.comment else { return }`

I ran a breakpoint and everything is coming out to nil ( the text of the comment, the user's information who posted the comment, everything) Does anyone know how I can fix this? I am also using Active Label so I'm not sure if that is playing a factor not. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the Edit Doug! I honestly wasn’t quite sure on which tags to use.

Comment: Off-topic but in the didSet method you are creating a local variable `user` that you use to get the url but shouldn't you use the `user` object you get from the database call for that?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson are you talking about the guard let User =...?

Comment: yes that's the one. You get a User object back from the database call so you should use that

Comment: No luck.. i dont know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson do you mind sharing code and giving me a quick example mate?

Comment: I wrote this, as mentioned, as an off-topic comment so no I do not have any code to share. I just don't understand why you fetch a user from the database when you don't use it and instead use the user and url from the comment (3rd and 4th guard statement)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yeah I completely understand mate. I’ll dig deeper and look into it but you’re totally on track

Comment: Where do you call `handleCommentTapped` from? Can you post code that calls this method, or mention how its linked/bound to 'tap' on comment cell?

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke I believe it’s called from that actual feed view controller. The rest is from the feed collection cell.

Comment: I then just created a protocol called FeedCellDelegate and created the function handleCommentTapped. Other functions include handleLikeTapped,OptionsTapped, etc

Comment: I will edit the question and include more details on what is getting called from what :)

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on `cell.comment` means, the cell being passed to this function is not accessible, either because its already deallocated, or due to access level.

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke I believe I saw a print statement regarding something being deallocated. Do you mind telling me how I can go about this? Does this mean I need to fix where the handleCommentTapped is coming from?

Comment: Also I’m not sure what the cell being deallocated means

Comment: For some reason you are not able to access the cell in your function. It is very unlikely that a cell that is just tapped will get deallocated. What is more likely is, the entity calling your function has a weak reference to the cell and that reference is not valid by the time control reaches your code. Simply making the input `cell` parameter optional (`CommentCell?`), and guarding against `cell?.comment`, will most likely avoid a crash, but not make your code work as you expect it to. Try that as a first step for you to continue debugging this without a crash.

Comment: Also, you mentioned other features like handleLikeTapped,OptionsTapped, etc, are they working correctly? If yes, you can compare how this case is different.

Comment: Actually you lit a bulb in my head. Let me explain the setup and hopefully it makes sense to you. I have a collection view that has a “posts” cell that contains a like button, options button, comment button etc. if a user taped the comment button they’re actually taken to a comment view controller that is another collection view that has a cell that contains comments users post. I tried following the same step I used for the feed collection view options button( that allows users to delete/report posts. And have a button similar that reports/deletes comments. So I apologize those other func’s

Comment: I mentioned are on a  separate view controller from the comments view controller.  If this is a little confusing I will definitely update my question and code .

Comment: Basically I wonder if it’s because I actually put the code in the feed view controller and not the comment view controller.. if that’s the case. Simple mistake I must have just thought since the comment button is apart of the feed view controller, the code needs to go there. I’ll check that out.

Comment: I am not sure i follow the entire workflow you mention above, but if there are multiple view controllers accessing / owning this code, yes, it might just be a very simple placement issue.

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke Guess that whole theory was a waste of time.. I actually did place the code in the correct area. I will go ahead and try your method and go from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, after 6 days of trying to figure out what I did wrong.. It appears all I forgot to add was

```swift
 cell.delegate = self
```

under  `cellForItemAt` on the collection view function. So if anyone has this issue I hope this helps!

I love coding!